# Why are there dots on Edges?

Tags: edges

Why are there dots on some of the edges while other edges do not have dots?

[image: Dots on Edges]

How do I remove these dots since they affect the subdivide smooth results?:

[image]

Comment: dots will be at the center of faces ,and it just happened that the edge is there,  the  mesh is messed up

Comment: remove doubles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out:
This happens when Extra Faces sneaked in where they shouldn't be, which happens an extrusion is done and never moved the geometry.

Solution: 
1.) Press "Tab" to go to Edit mode
2.) Press "A" to Select All 
3.) Press "W" to open Specials Menu
4.) Select "Remove Doubles"

Thanks gimble3d & Sanne from #blenderchat

Answer (score 7):

That means you have zero sized faces over those edges and you mesh topology is messy. Probably the leftover of unfinished operations or the result of some undesired zero sized extrude.

You can try and clean it up by selecting all with <kbd>A</kbd> and then with <kbd>W</kbd> Menu > *Remove Doubles* option.