# Bevel only works in 2 dimensions

Tags: geometry

I want to bevel 3 cubes.

To do that, I following [a tutorial](https://youtu.be/HfDBVjLyQtc?t=89).

In this tutorial, the author accomplishes the following:

[image]

I try to do the same, but for me, it doesn't do the same.
Instead, it seems to bevel in 2 dimensions only:

[image]

What am I doing differently than the tutor?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: hm, maybe its a problem how you have 3 faces and not one, and it could be how your in face select and he might be in edge.

Comment: It works correctly for me. Either upload your file here or describe precisely how you're trying to do it.

Comment: @JohnEason I have added my blend file to the question.

Comment: I'll have a look.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49632/why-are-there-dots-on-edges

Comment: That appears to have been made from a single plane rather than 3 cubes (Plane 2 in the outliner) and the object's scale is all over the place anyhow so I'm not surprised you're having issuse!

Comment: @JohnEason What do you mean by "the object's scale is all over the place"?

Comment: @JohnEason What is the difference between a plane extruded to form a cube and a cube?

Comment: you need to apply the scale in Object mode (Ctrl A), you have overlapping vertices so you need to merge the vertices (Alt M), and you need to recalculate the normals (Alt N)

Comment: When you are in face select mode and you see dots in the middle of edges, it means you have zero-area faces there and you need to remove double geometry

Comment: Sorry not to reply earlier. It was almost 1am here when I wrote my last comment and I've been asleep! I think you've had the answers I was going to give though. If you select your object, press 'N' in Object mode and look at the scale in the side panel, you'd see that the scale was 0.139, -0.046, 0.26. Bevel and other operations really don't like uneven scale so as moonboots says you need to apply it via Ctrl A and you'll then see that it's set to 1 for all dimensions. As Gorgius says, you also need to get rid of double geometry as seen by the dots on the edges.

Comment: Following on from my last comment, you'll still have problems even if you've removed duplicates, reset the scale and recalculated the normals because the left-hand two "cubes" don't have a face between them. Even if if you put one in (select the loop in edge mode and 'F' to fill), bevelling will only put a bevel right round the front of the object.